# Mocking pure virtual methods if class also has non-virtual methods?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, c++11

I am currently using HippoMocks as mocking framework, and can't figure out how to mock the pure virtual method `MockMe()` in the code below. I do *not* want to mock any of the non-virtual methods (which is likely not even possible), instead I want them to do what they are meant for and call the mocked virtual one.

```
struct A
{
  void Run() { RunImpl(); }
  virtual void RunImpl() = 0;
};

struct B : public A
{
    //implement A::RunImpl
  void RunImpl() { MockMe(); }

    //this one I want to mock
  virtual void MockMe() = 0;
};

MockRepository mocks;
B* b = mocks.InterfaceMock< B >();
mocks.OnCall( b, B::MockMe );
b->Run(); //throws NotImplementedException for Run()
```

Is there any way to get this working with HippoMocks? Or with another framework? Or with some source modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update/answer: I found a way around it by deriving a new class from B and adding a helper to forward the calls to the appropriate method. Apart from that it's also important to use `ClassMock` instead of `InterfaceMock`.

So, using the example above, this works:

```
struct MockHelper : public B
{
  void InvokeRunImpl()
  {
    B::RunImpl();
  }

  virtual void MockMe()
  {
    //never called, but must be defined so MockHelper can be instantiated
  }
};

MockHelper* b = mocks.ClassMock< MockHelper >();
auto invokeIt = [b]() { b->InvokeRunImpl(); };
mocks.OnCall( b, MockHelper::RunImpl ).Do( invokeIt );
mocks.OnCall( b, MockHelper::MockMe );
//ok now: calls A::Run, which calls mocked RunImpl, which in turn
//calls InvokeRunImpl, which in turn calls B::RunImpl
b->Run();
```

Comment: If you are OK with C++0x solutions, you should add that tag to your question.

Comment: done.. could be done with 'standard' c++ off course but that's a lot more typing ;P

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used mocking frameworks, but this should be one of the easier things to do...

Extend the `B` class with a `Mock` class, where you only override the pure virtual methods and forward on the constructors. Then instantiate the derived class and pass it as a reference/pointer to the mocked class, which is something the rest of the application is probably ready to handle: if the class has pure virtual functions, then the application is using it polymorphically, through pointers and/or references.

Comment: I read your answer a couple of times but failed to understand what you mean ;] Could you provide some small sample code?